# How to replace values in column in Power Query Advanced Editor

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm quite new to PowerBI and am unable to solve this.

So I have a few data files in my folder containing sales data.
My column names are something like "Sales | 10/10/2020", "Sales | 11/10/2020" and so forth... As such my sales columns in each file have a different column name.

I want to get my PowerBI to auto transform my data in my folder for me, one such step is replacing blank values to 0 in all my Sales columns.

I realise that my PowerBI has been giving me errors because the sample transformation references my columns from my sample file by column name. And then it's unable to find the same column name in the rest of the files (since they all have different dates).

I would like to ask if it's possible to reference the columns by index position instead of name in my replace value step, to prevent this error.

Or are there better ways to get around this? Thanks so much in advance!

I've tried to convert my columns into index positions with Columns=Table.ColumnsNames(Source) to turn all my columns into a list and then referencing my sales column by using list as such Columns{17}.

But when I replace my column name in my replace value code in Advanced Editor, it tells me that there's an error where value cannot be converted to type table

Comment: No data; No code => unable to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your column names are dates, don't you want to unpivot first and then change the names?

Answer (score 0):

Pick up the column names by column number,

```
Columns = {Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"){1},Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"){2},Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"){3}},
```

or pick up any column name that contains **Sales**

```
Columns=List.FindText(Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere"),"Sales" ),
```

then do the replace

```
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"PriorStepNameHere",null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Columns),
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, as i had to promote the headers into column let
    Source = Csv.Document(Parameter2,[Delimiter=" ", Columns=66, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{ {"SALES | 30-12-2021", type number}, {"SALES | 06-01-2022", type number}})
    Columns = List.FindText(Table.ColumnNames(Source),"Sales" ), 
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,Columns),
in
    #"Changed Type"

Comment: If I were to do my transformation in my query alone (without helper query), and my source is a folder, how can I get around this and get my source to reference opening each CSV file in my folder instead?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are looking for. I provided a method to replace nulls with zeroes, which was the request.  If you have additional questions, then accept this issue as solved and start another question instead of changing the requirements.  If you start a  new question, include a paste of your existing code which was lacking here